# Marklogic- How get a list of elements in a document

Tags: marklogic

I describe table_name in Oracle to show list of fields.  How can I do that in Marklogic to get a list of elements in a document. Thanks in advance.

Oracle:
DESCRIBE EMP_DETAILS

Name

EMPLOYEE_ID
 JOB_ID
 MANAGER_ID
 DEPARTMENT_ID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely not an apples-to-apples comparison, since documents in MarkLogic equate more to rows than tables.  But since documents are self-describing, you're right that you can ask for a list of elements in a document.  Using XQuery, try this:

```
doc($uri)//*/name()
```

That selects all elements, and prints their name.  In MarkLogic, that will also show you the names of properties in a JSON document.

But if you really want to do something more like Oracle, with a describe table, you can create views and use good 'ol SQL to describe them.

Comment: When I want a quick look at all of the elements and want to be aware of their structure, i use a slightly extended version of Sam's example:  fn:distinct-values(doc($uri)//* ! xdmp:path(.) ! replace(., "\[[0-9]?\]", "")) ! replace(., "/\*:", "/")

Comment: Yet another variant -- to collect all of the element names for a random sample of 1,000 documents, try something like fn:distinct-values(fn:subsequence(cts:search(fn:collection(),cts:true-query(),"score-random"), 1, 1000)//element()!name(.))